# Over Function Program R

Tags: r, spatial

I am trying to use the `over` function from the `sp` package on program R in order to determine the time that my spatial locations where inside a polygon. When I use the over function however, it does not keep the time of the locations, because the over function keeps the attributes of the spatial object y.

```
Over function - consistent spatial overlay for points, grids and polygons: at the spatial locations of object x retrieves the indexes or attributes from spatial object y
    over(x, y, returnList = FALSE, fn = NULL, ...)
```

For example: I have a `SpatialPointsDataFrame` of different datetimes associated with each spatial point.

```
structure(list(ID = c("100", "100", "100", "100", "100", "100"
), date = c("Tuesday, December 19, 2017", "Friday, December 29, 2017", 
"Tuesday, December 19, 2017", "Friday, January 12, 2018", "Thursday, January 11, 2018", 
"Friday, January 12, 2018"), time = c("10:45:11 PM", "3:15:13 AM", 
"9:45:13 AM", "9:00:47 AM", "10:45:14 PM", "2:15:14 AM"), Lat = c(32.5936574, 
32.5936428, 32.5936927, 32.5937924, 32.5938921, 32.5938511), 
    Long = c(-90.2295604, -90.2295496, -90.2295391, -90.2295182, 
    -90.2294759, -90.2294755), DOP = c(3, 2.400000095, 3.400000095, 
    6.400000095, 3.799999952, 4.800000191), datetime = c("2017-12-19 22:45:11", 
    "2017-12-29 03:15:13", "2017-12-19 09:45:13", "2018-01-12 09:00:47", 
    "2018-01-11 22:45:14", "2018-01-12 02:15:14")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

And I have a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame`

```
    structure(list(Id = 1:6, Size__sq_m = c("4620", "8596", "17808", 
"9697", "35585", "2275"), Lat = c(32.7258477025, 32.7191928261, 
32.6850642603, 32.6823323788, 32.6513297432, 32.5955077182), 
    Long = c(-90.1742789845, -90.1811643753, -90.1846049731, 
    -90.1848020957, -90.125689296, -90.213027021), Count = c(1, 
    1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Size_Acres = c(1.14155754658, 2.1241603074, 
    4.40033391162, 2.3960867035, 8.79335702275, 0.562079564917
    ), NEAR_FID = c("-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1", "-1"), NEAR_DIST = c(10616635.9574, 
    10617610.4428, 10620532.4104, 10620721.7618, 10619113.4374, 
    10629445.487)), row.names = 0:5, class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to know the exact times when a location was inside polygon. Is this possible with the `over` function or is there another way to accomplish this? Would it further be possible to only keep the first location of each ID that is located in a polygon? So if there are 5 spatial locations inside of a polygon within 2 hours, only keep that first location?

Comment: Neither one of those has a class of "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame" or "SpatialPointsDataFrame". You can see that by inspection of the "class" argument to `structure`